# Error in dockers when using network builder to start up

Tags: docker, corda

I am following the documentation in https://docs.corda.net/network-builder.html. To build a test network. After the start up, i see in the output logs that dockers are all started up.

When i do docker ps. I dont see any dockers. 
docker ps -a - lists all the dockers but they exited with below error. 
"standard_init_linux.go:190: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"

Can you help me fixing this ?

**Update**

[image]

Comment: This isn't something I've seen before. This might be a Docker error and not something specific to Corda. Can you also add a Docker tag

Comment: @CaisManai I tried using builder on both mac and ubuntu.. Doesnt seem to work. Any help ?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for you time @nelaturuk

this is being tracked under: https://github.com/corda/corda/issues/3961

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with line ending in run-corda.sh. Building a new jar with dos2unix in place will fix this.  Corda team will fix this version 3.3.